# Is Lakshmi Devi two handed or four handed according to this dhyanamantra?

Tags: puranas, mantras, lakshmi

In Bengal, Lakshmi is worshipped by the following dhyanamantra:

> Paasha-Akshamaalika-Ambhoja-Srinivir yamyasaumyaoh
>   Padmasanatham dhyatet cha Sriyam Trailokyamataram
>   Gauravarnam surupaam cha sarvaalankaarabhushitaam
>    Raukmapadma-byagrakaraam varadaam dakshinena tu

Here Pasha, Akshamala,Padma and Srini along with abhaya mudra have been mentioned.But in Bengal Lakshmi is always depicted with two hands.

Does the dhyanamantra clearly say that she has two hands?

Comment: Is it Tantric mantra ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto yesi think so.But i did not get it in the Tantric texts nor did I get in any puraana as yet. It is there in the puja-paddhati books

Comment: Which puja-paddhati book ? Can you tell the name ?

Comment: TheLittleNaruto its used in all bengali puja paddhati books that contain lakshmi puja including shyamacharan kaviratna

Comment: In that case only who understand Bengali and has read that puja paddhati book, can answer that.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto anyone having enough knowledge of sanskrit shd be able to provide the meaning

Comment: In that case, I would need the book. Can you share a link ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto The mantra given here is in Sanskrit and not in Bengali .. even if the Puja Paddhati book is in Bengali, mantras given therein will be in Sanskrit only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Dhyana Mantra for the Kojagari Lakshmi Puja.

I am giving the translation by Gautam Kumar Jha. It's there in one of my Sarva Devadevi Puja Paddhati books.

> You are the mother of the three worlds; you are of the form Shri. In
>   your left hand you have the Ankusha and a golden lotus held in vara(boon-giving) mudra; in your right hand
>   you hold the Pasha and the rosary beads. Decked in jewels and
>   ornaments, you are beautiful and of a fair complexion. You are seated in
>   the lotus-posture.

So, the deity is apparently having two hands and not four.

Comment: Yes I m correcting that .. the translator gives " dakshin haste bara mudra diteche abhaya" @Partha

Comment: I think translator meant "by showing vara mudra she is giving assurance" .. Abhaya mudra of course is not talked abt in the mantra @Partha

Comment: Yes it's perfect  ..  @Partha